# In meteor, how to create dynamic id with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a card displaying dynamically when I submit the form.

Here is code:

```
    <template name="workflow">

    <div id="newActionCard">

        {{#each newaction}}
                     <div class="workflowcard">
                     <div class="module-card-small">
                         <div class="res-border"></div>
                        <div class="card-img">{{team}}</div>
                        <div class="res-content">

                        <div class=" newaction-name">{{action_title}}</div><hr>
                        <div class="newaction-des">{{description}}</div>
                       <!-- <div class=" due-on">Due on:{{d_date}}</div><hr>-->
                        </div>
                          <div class="due">

                           Due on:
                            <div>
                                <div class="day-stamp">{{weekday d_date}}</div>
                            <div class="date-stamp">{{date d_date}}</div>
                            <div class="month-stamp">{{month d_date}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                           {{> actioncardsubcontent}} 
</div>
         <div class="btn-box">
          <button type="button" class="cancelsub">New Action</button>
          <button type="submit" class="createbtnsub">Show Options</button>
        </div>
    </div>

                    {{/each}}                                                                                                                                              
            </div>
        </div>  

    </template>

<template name="actioncardsubcontent">

    <div class="subcontent">

            <div class="modulepath"><div>{{module_list}}</div></div>
            <div class="linkto"><div>Linked To: &nbsp;<div class="linkto-color">{{link}}</div></div></div>
            <div class="description"><div>Notes:<br>{{description}}</div></div>
            </div>

</template>
```

when I submit the form the card gets generated with some hidden part by the below JS.

```
Template.actioncardsubcontent.rendered = function(){
    this.$(".subcontent").hide();
};
```

When I click on "Show Options" button the hidden part will display. and below is the code for that

```
Template.workflow.events({
"click .createbtnsub":function(){
$('.subcontent).show();
}
});
```

My question is,  when I click on show options button at the output the hidden part is displaying for each card at a time not to the particular card. The reason is I have given the same class name for each and I want to create a dynamic id that allos particular card hide content on click. How to write it. I am stuck there. Can anyone help?

I have tried with below code but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="action" id={{_id}}> {{> actioncardsubcontent}} </div>
```

and in JS i replaced `$('.subcontent').show();` with `var id="#"+this._id;` `$(id).show();` but it doesn't work. Let me know how to I write for dynamic Id generation for each click.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of your `id={{_id}}` solution is correct, but you have added the `id` attribute to a different element than what you hide. Try this:

```html
<template name="actioncardsubcontent">
  <div class="subcontent" id={{_id}}>
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Your event handler in the upper template should still find the element if you do

```js
$('#' + this._id).show();
```

***If this does not help***, it may be because your data does not have an `_id` attribute. In that case you could use some other unique identifier or add one with `Random.id()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as this has worked for me.

```
    function(){
        $('.className').each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', 'idName'+i);
     });
```